# How to edit webpages of a simple website without editing HTML?

Tags: php, html

How to install/integrate a graphical webpage editor in a simple website?

Or any other editor like ckeditor?

Comment: what do you mean? Like dreamweaver?

Comment: @Ashley Wrench I just want to add an edit button and do edits and save button to edit website pages,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any WYSIWYG (what you see is what you get) editor will just open html files and you can edit them from there. For example, Dreamweaver will edit a html page in a Graphical Interface.

If your looking at something "in house", where you can go to mysite.com and login then edit the site. I would look at something like [drupal](http://drupal.org). (its like word press, just focuses more on multi page sites rather than a blog)

Comment: ok thanks for answer. As far as I know, drupal is complete cms not just webpage editor or file editor, is there any other only file editors available to edit my webpage and save, is it possible to make WYSIWYG (ckeditor) to edit my server files/webpages?

Comment: Something like ckeditor is more for client end stuff, like form replies and document creation within a web app. Anything is possible, and I don't see why you wouldn't be able to. I dont think your going to have much luck finding what your after as something like drupal is more and better. If your looking to make just a simple change, try Dreamweaver, download the html file you want to edit, and open it in Dreamweaver. Link To Product: http://www.adobe.com/uk/products/dreamweaver.html

Answer (score 0):

http://innovastudio.com/builderdemo/example1.html

This will help. A drag drop builder for eidting HTML pages